# Different values when getting IP Address on Android

Tags: android, mobile, network-programming, ip

I try to get external IP Address value on Android when I am connected in Mobile Network.

I use the following code :

```
public static String ipAddress() {
    String ipAddress = "N/A";
    try {
        for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface
                .getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
            NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();

            for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf
                    .getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();

                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                    ipAddress = inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString();
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (SocketException ex) {
    }

    return ipAddress;
}
```

It returns me a value. To be sure, I also used a service like that in my application : http://ifconfig.me/ip.json that returns the external IP address.

My problem is that the service returns me a different value that the method ipAddress().

So, can you help me to understand what is the problem with ipAddress() method ? What does it mean the value getted from ipAddress() ?

Thanks for your help.

Sylvain

Comment: And what values do you get? I'm betting you locally get the *localhost* address, but the web-service gives you the address given to your phone from the network provider.

Comment: ipAddress() method returns value like 10.205.250.163 . Localhost address will rather like 192.168.xx.xx no ?

Comment: Localhost is almost always 127.0.0.1, but can be anything of the form 127.x.x.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using a cellular network?

You say you're seeing a 10.x.x.x IP address.  10.x.x.x is like 192.168.x.x -- it's a private-network internal address, not a globally meaningful address.  You're inside a NAT setup of some kind.

On cellular data, you're basically always behind a giant NAT system that is run by the cellular carrier themselves.  Ordinary internet sites and machines usually cannot open connections to mobile devices because of the NAT system.  The cell carrier certainly won't set up port forwarding for you.

If you're on a wifi network, it just means that whoever set up the private internal network decided to use 10.x.x.x IP addresses instead of 192.168.x.x -- it's pretty common.

In either case, it means that the IP address that is visible from your code is not usable by external machines or devices.  Nobody (at least, nobody outside your local network) can initiate a connection *to* your device with those addresses.

Comment: In addition, every time you connect to the internet trough a cellular carrier, you get different IP assigned every time.